# infinite series ($ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $) that its partial sum isn't bounded from above or from below. but if index shifted would converge.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Do you have an example of an infinite series $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $$
that its partial sum isn't bounded from above or from below.

but you can change the indexing of the series so it would converge ?

what would be the index change so that the series would converge?

i think about $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{(-1^n)n}  $$

am i right ?
is this the solution ?

so that if i take only even numbers or odd numbers i get a series that doesnt diverge right?

[image]

Comment: Look up the Riemann rearrangement theorem and the concept of conditional convergence.

Comment: i looked in wikipedia bout Riemann rearrangement theorem  and found about  ```the series 1 − 1 + 1/2 − 1/2 + 1/3 − 1/3 + ⋯ converges to 0 (for a sufficiently large number of terms, the partial sum gets arbitrarily near to 0); but replacing all terms with their absolute values gives 1 + 1 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/3 + ⋯, which sums to infinity``` i need the opposite, i need that partial sum doenst converge but the sum with rerrangment converge

Comment: What does the rearrangement thm tell you?

Comment: rearrangement thm tell me : ```if an infinite series of real numbers is conditionally convergent, then its terms can be arranged in a permutation so that the new series converges to an arbitrary real number, or diverges.``` i need the partial sum to not bounded from above or from below. and the sum itself to converge if i change index is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, so any conditionally convergent series can be made to diverge. This gives you a divergent series that can be rearranged to converge.

Comment: Also, your example of the alternating harmonic series is correct. The procedure how to rearrange it in a way that it converges to any arbitrary value or diverge is nicely described on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Comment: so how would you look at the partial sum to not be bounded ?

Comment: the example i game is bounded , but i need it to not be bounded , do you have an example maybe or an hint for me how can i look at serires the its partial sum not bounded ?

Comment: Any partial sum is a sum of a finite number of values. It is therefore always going to be bounded as any finite set has a well-defined maximum and minimum. Did you mean to say a partial sum that's not convergent?